# Form tag or Form ID in Content Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

### Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Master.master.cs" Inherits="Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    <%--Place for title--%>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>        
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
       <link href="css/loginPopup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />            
</head>      
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>            
      <div class="body1">      
            <div class="main">
……
……
```

### Content Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="register.aspx.cs" Inherits="register" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<title>Register with Us</title>
  <link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#form1").validationEngine();
        });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="main_body" Runat="Server">
        <div class="body2">
            <div class="main">
…….
…….
```

### Problem

Dear Sir, As you can see in my above **Content Page** , there is a jQuery function using form id(`form1`). the problem is that form/form ID is in master page. That's why this jQuery function is not working. Pls help me by telling solution.

Comment: Your issue is client side, so provide the rendered html, not server side script.

Comment: Try to access using class name in content page. Change `<form id="form1" runat="server" class="FormContent">  ` and `jQuery(".FormContent").validationEngine();` this way you will not get any error.

Comment: @user2791156 - have you managed to get it sorted? Let me know if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net webforms generated html elements do not have the same server side Id, but you can access that Id by ClinetID property:

```
jQuery("#<%=form1.ClientID %>").validationEngine();
```

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery Selectors

In your jQuery selector you will need to take into account that the name of the form may have changed, especially since it is `runat="server"`.

Use a selector that uses a wildcard search for the form, something like this should work:

```
$("form[id$='form1']")
```

Or more specifically for your usage scenario:

```
jQuery("form[id$='form1']").validationEngine(); 
// $ is a shortcut for jQuery so either can be used
```

Check out the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more options.

### Client Side vs Server Side

I generally opt for client side javascript and only mix the 2 where absolutely necessary. In these cases I opt for using the IIFE pattern and inject into some properties server side values (i.e. using the `<%=form1.ClientID %>` syntax as suggested by VahidND). I try to keep a bare minimum of javascript in my aspx files. This helps with the organisation of your web application and makes it a load easier to debug in Firefox and Chrome. Generally speaking you can get by with just using the `$=` syntax of the jQuery **ends with** selector *et al*; you will find you will use it *LOADS* as your pages become nearer to real life complexity.

### ASP.NET Web Forms

One major drawback of ASP.NET Web Forms is that you are limited to a single form per page. If you are adding your own form to the page this may also be causing you some problems.